# Webstorm - How to add browser arguments for javascript debug configuration

Tags: javascript, dart, webstorm

How does one add browser arguments (such as --ignore-certificate-errors) for a javascript debug configuration in Webstorm? I'm debugging Dart in the Dartium browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a web browser for each set of arguments. When you select a browser (For example Dartium, there is a pencil below the `+`,`-` buttons which opens a dialog for `Command line options` and profile directory.

You can reach the browser configurations dialog from the Debug Configurations clicking on `[...]` on the right of `Browser [Dartium|v][...]` or `File` > `Settings` > `Tools` > `Web Browsers` (WebStorm 9 beta)